# Active Rendering using Only Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to perform active rendering with double buffering using only Swing components (no Canvas or any other AWT components)? This means there should be no reliance on the EDT to handle any aspect of rendering.

EDIT: The program that I am writing that prompted this question is not fullscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to perform active rendering with only Swing if you use the `BufferStrategy` provided by `JFrame.getBufferStrategy()`. From that point you can act as if you were using the `BufferStrategy` from a `Canvas`.

Answer (score 2):

Java supports active rendering in the [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html):
[Passive vs. Active Rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html)

But also on AWT there are ways to take explicit control over the rendering (without having to go full screen):

- Have your rendering component extend `java.awt.Canvas`
- Ignore repaint requests from the EDT: `setIgnoreRepaint(true);`
- Create a buffer strategy for double buffering (page flip)
- Update your buffer after painting: `strategy.show()`
- Bring your updated graphics to the screen: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`

Here's a good article on that topic, including an example:
 [Java Game (Actually the most efficient way to repaint)](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/113451-java-game-actually-the-most-efficient-way-to-repaint/)

Comment: Hmm... I have written programs that use the Canvas to render. However as I specified in my question I wanted a solution that did not use AWT components such as Canvas. This is because according to [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,26060.) forum thread it is faster to use JPanel for painting than Canvas (however, they may be mistaken).