# Where can I find the implemented abstract Graphic class?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

An abstract class is passed into paintComponent , and functions can be performed on it . Anyway , it sounds not real. So there must be a definition of concrete Graphics . I'm chewing on if I can refer to that concrete class and whether it's possible to skip over re-defining paintComponent process to directly draw things .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active Rendering using Only Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986963/active-rendering-using-only-swing)

Comment: the Implementation shouldn't and doesn't matter - code against its public API and be happy :) it's beyond your control anyways ..

Answer (score 1):

Indeed looking at the API the [JComponent.paint()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) method requires one parameter: [Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html), a class that is abstract.

But that is just the API and it means at runtime some concise implementation needs to be passed. If you read the API documentation there are two known subclasses: [DebugGraphics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/DebugGraphics.html) (which is not abstract) and [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) which is abstract again.

When you run some Swing application you will see that the components receive implementations of Graphics2D. In my java-11-openjdk-amd64 the class sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D is the concise class.

You can find out by subclassing any JComponent and overriding the paint() method with

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    System.out.println(g.getClass().getName());
    super.paint(g);
}
```